# Practical case JVM tunning to avoid full GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I have [read](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) and [read](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) but they only explain Garbage Collection in a theoretically way, I think it must be really complicated to explain how to solve a practical issue.

My configuration

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk6
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms272m -Xmx272m -XX:MaxPermSize=272m -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
```

When the server starts, all goes smooth as silk

```
29.846: [GC 29.846: [DefNew: 74109K->1940K(83520K), 0.0125820 secs] 106982K->34813K(269248K), 0.0126230 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
30.002: [GC 30.002: [DefNew: 76016K->1502K(83520K), 0.0092930 secs] 108889K->34375K(269248K), 0.0093380 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
31.745: [GC 31.745: [DefNew: 75443K->4722K(83520K), 0.0369630 secs] 108316K->37595K(269248K), 0.0370130 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
33.122: [GC 33.122: [DefNew: 78962K->6065K(83520K), 0.0444350 secs] 111835K->39481K(269248K), 0.0444850 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 
34.183: [GC 34.183: [DefNew: 80258K->4880K(83520K), 0.0371350 secs] 113674K->41044K(269248K), 0.0371830 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
```

The amount of memory which is not being collected grows and sometimes some full gc are performed, but the system recovers from these

```
356.210: [Full GC 356.210: [Tenured: 74012K->66067K(185728K), 0.2215880 secs] 126231K->66067K(269248K), [Perm : 70207K->70207K(70208K)], 0.2216510 secs] [Times: user=0.22 sys=0.00, real=0.22 secs]
```

Finally it only performs full gc

```
61587.386: [Full GC 61587.386: [Tenured: 185728K->185728K(185728K), 0.4045190 secs] 269107K->188117K(269248K), [Perm : 85394K->85394K(85504K)], 0.4045860 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs] 
61587.820: [Full GC 61587.820: [Tenured: 185728K->185728K(185728K), 0.4075960 secs] 268851K->187688K(269248K), [Perm : 85394K->85394K(85504K)], 0.4076610 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs] 
61588.258: [Full GC 61588.258: [Tenured: 185728K->185727K(185728K), 0.4184530 secs] 269042K->187217K(269248K), [Perm : 85394K->85248K(85504K)], 0.4185420 secs] [Times: user=0.41 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs] 
61588.702: [Full GC 61588.702: [Tenured: 185727K->185727K(185728K), 0.4054800 secs] 269129K->187216K(269248K), [Perm : 85248K->85248K(85504K)], 0.4055560 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs] 
61589.145: [Full GC 61589.145: [Tenured: 185727K->185727K(185728K), 0.4042100 secs] 269048K->187247K(269248K), [Perm : 85248K->85248K(85504K)], 0.4042770 secs] [Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs]
```

and exceptions arise

```
Jun 10, 2015 5:12:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
```

The web application runs with Java 1.6 on Tomcat 7 Server and uses Struts 2 (2.3.24) Any help would be so much appreciated because I am just a java programmer and I didn't know java had these big caveats under the hood. Thanks

Comment: You have a memory leak of some description. You are allocating objects and not making them eligible for GC. You need to take a heap dump and work out what's going on.

Comment: You definitely seem to be handing on to objects and not releasing them.  This could be a bug ("memory leak") or it could just mean that your server needs lots of memory.  Can you increase the perm gen?  If it still throws errors you'll have to work out where the objects are being held, as Boris mentions.

Comment: Also, your current memory maximums, 272m, doesn't seem like that much.  Can you allocate 2-4 gigs for the server? that would seem better, although again if it just runs out of memory you may have a leak, or you could just have high memory requirements.

Comment: I dont think my code has memory leaks, as it has been working for years. I think the app has grown and now it has to handle a bigger amount of data. I can adjust any parameter. Please suggest me an entire configuration. Thanks markspace

Comment: *"Please suggest me an entire configuration"* instead of asking for a ready-made solution it would be advisable that you try to understand your system/what went wrong so you can solve such problems on your own in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is much more fundamental than a full GC. You didn't even try to understand what is happening right now, i.e. what current default settings apply, let alone changing the defaults.

Also Full GCs are not necessarily bad in themselves.

> -Xmx272m

This is the max heap size. I.e. the maximum amount of heap the application is allowed to use. The guides you linked have *several chapters on this topic.*

Which part of the guides have you not understood?

> DefNew

This is the serial young gen collector. It's singlethreaded (read: slow)

> [Times: user=0.41 sys=0.00, real=0.41 secs]

user == real time implies also single-threaded old gen collection.

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk6

java 6 has long reached end of life. Update to java 8, it provides new and improved collectors

> I have read and read but they only explain Garbage Collection in a theoretically way

The guides you linked explain many available options, not just academic theory. It doesn't seem like you have even experimented with any of the options.

> because I am just a java programmer and I didn't know java had these big caveats under the hood.

GC effectively is part of java. As a programmer you need to understand it, because ignoring it will make your application crash or fail to perform properly.

If you think that you do not need to know you are wrong.

Comment: so with my configuration I am creating a heap of 272m (-Xmx272m) and wrongly I am assigning all of it to perm generation (-XX:MaxPermSize=272m) ?

Answer (score 1):

There is two strategies to prevent full gc:

1) minimize count of long-living objects. Perfectly to zero. If you store link to some object for time that more than young gc interval that object will live in heap until full gc. Usually it's imposible to create java app completely without long-living objects but you can reduce count of it.

Worst situation when your app produce long-living objects and never frees it, it works like memory leak and lead to outofmemory error

2) enlarge heap and young generation size (1st give you more time before gc, second enlarge interval between young gc (less long-lived objects). Prevent full gc by rebooting app (based on heap size for example). Be careful. Big young gen leads to bigger pause on young gc.

modern G1 gc (default in Java 8?) should decrease count of full gc calls

I have experience with app that use 10G young Gen 60G heap at start and max heap size over 200GB. Full gc never called (we reboot it every 2-5 days). Young gc pause 0.1-0.3 seconds every 1-5 minutes.

Comment: also agree with a the8472. you should upgrade to java 8. It should be compatible with your app

Comment: How do you indicate the young gen amount, the heap at start and the max heap, which are the correct parameters? Are you sure restarting the server is like reseting the memory counter?

Comment: i dont think that restarting app for avoiding gc is good general practice. But it can be used for extremely big heaps (not your case). Optimal parameters adjusted experimentally. each combination of app and kind of gc has its own optimal settings. Just try and see what happend. Just switching to java 8 (with g1 gc) and enlarge -XmX can help you i guess. g1 settings tutorial http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html , g1 tuning: http://www.infoq.com/articles/tuning-tips-G1-GC

Comment: thank you paul_di, lets try this: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk8
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=80 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500"

Comment: be careful. check java version from code: System.getProperty("java.version"). Some apps can use java from PATH variable, not from JAVA_HOME. Have you seen any improvements?

Comment: yes, it is java 8 because log messages are different. it is still not working, now I get lots of GC pauses and Full GC with previous configuration (G1GC). I dont know what to do. My server has 1.4 Gb memory, just in case you want to help me